# Is it possible to show certificate info on the location bar using Cordova InAppBrowser plugin?

Tags: javascript, cordova, inappbrowser

I have a cordova app where I redirect login to an auth provider using cordova InAppBrowser plugin:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/#show

I want to show the certificate info like we have on left side of location toolbar like in chrome:

[image]

So far could not find any solution by myself, is there an alternative option ?

Comment: Hi Biswas, Have you got any option for this to show certificate info on location bar.